# Pass parameter query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get lat, lng according to the city. When I latterly write the city ('Buffalo') within the query it works. I want to use different cities.

```
public function getLatLng($data, $city) {
    $count_data = count($data);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count_data; $i++) {
        $latlngs = array();
        $stmt = $this -> conn -> prepare("SELECT g.lat, g.lng
          FROM news_locations AS nl INNER JOIN geolocations AS g
          ON g.geolocation_id = nl.geolocation_id
          WHERE nl.news_id = ". $data[$i]["news_id"] ."
          AND nl.is_deleted = 0 AND g.city = 'Buffalo'");
        if ($stmt -> execute()) {
            $stmt -> bind_result($lat, $lng);
            while($stmt -> fetch()) {
               $row = array();
               $row["lat"] = $lat;
               $row["lng"] = $lng;
               array_push($latlngs, $row);
            }
            $stmt -> close();
        }
        $data[$i]['latlng'] = array_values($latlngs);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

I have tried to write

```
AND g.city = " . $city);
```

Also tried

```
AND g.city = :city");
if ($stmt -> execute(array('city' => $city))) {
```

Both did not work. How to pass the parameter $city to query?

Comment: You have to bind the variables to the sql statement.

Comment: @Jumana you have been provided poor guidance.  If you used the accepted answer in your application,  then your application is not secure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Concatenate strings and variables :

```
g.city = '"  . $city . "'"
```

like:

```
 $stmt = $this -> conn -> prepare("SELECT g.lat, g.lng
          FROM news_locations AS nl INNER JOIN geolocations AS g
          ON g.geolocation_id = nl.geolocation_id
          WHERE nl.news_id = ". $data[$i]["news_id"] ."
          AND nl.is_deleted = 0 AND g.city = '"  . $city . "'");
```

Comment: Even if this works it is NOT best practice because it fails to utilize a prepared statement to secure the query.  No one should use this answer.